# Export dictionary within dictionary to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have a PowerShell dictionary that has arrays in it, populated via

```
foreach ($res in $result){
    foreach ($proper in $props){ 
        if ($proper.EntityId -eq $res.id){
            $ht[$res.name] += @($res.name,$proper.Val,$proper.PropDefId)
        }
    }
}
```

`@{key,@(value1,value2,value3)}` and I'm looking for a way to export it to CSV in the

```
dictionary,value1,value2,value3
```

format.

If I only had one value I'd do a `$ht.GetEnumerator() | Export-Csv csvname.csv`.
I've tried doing a `$ht.GetEnumerator | $_.GetEnumerator |`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: In PS2+ it's simply `New-Object PSObject -Property $hashtable`, see [How do you add more property values to a custom object](//stackoverflow.com/a/36201169)

Comment: Would I create an object inside the internal foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the elements of the outer hashtable, create objects from the inner hashtables (like [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841565/export-to-csv-powershell-getenumerator-on-dictionary-within-dictionary#comment66972871_39841565) suggested), and add the keys of the outer hashtable as a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx). Then export the result to a CSV

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
  $key = $_.Name
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $_.Value |
    Select-Object @{n='Dictionary';e={$key}},*
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

---

**Edit:** You have a dictionary of arrays, not a dictionary of dictionaries. It can be exported to a CSV like this:

```
$ht.Keys | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'key'    = $_
    'value1' = $ht[$_][0]
    'value2' = $ht[$_][1]
    'value3' = $ht[$_][2]
  }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: This results in

New-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Collections.IDictionary' required by parameter 'Property'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\Desktop\work_1_array.ps1:39 char:39
+   New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $_.Value |
+                                       ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: @Mike That's because you have a dictionary of arrays, not a dictionary of dictionaries like you claimed. See updated answer.